# Uniquely representing tree elements

Tags: java, treeview

I want to make my TreeView remember the selected items after `refresh/setInput`. (Let's pretend the Java TreeView doesn't remember the state). Since the TreeView will get setInput, so the element reference won't persist.

I am thinking to store the selected element by its full path in an `ArrayList<String>`. (e.g. it looks like `["root_name", "2nd_level_name", "3rd_level_name", "node_name"]`). With the full path, I can locate the same element in the refreshed TreeView again.

I was wondering if there's any better way doing this? Or any existing libraries in Java can do this?